# How to fix autoloader for global apps in composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to create a template [installer](https://github.com/eru123/linker-installer) from scratch for my [PHP Framework](https://github.com/eru123/linker) project and it is my first time working with composer global so I am completely lost.

on the [main file](https://github.com/eru123/linker-installer/blob/main/linker) I tried to include the autoloader like this:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$dir = __DIR__;

if(is_file(__DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php")){
    require_once(__DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php"); // this is the line 6
} elseif (is_file(__DIR__."/../autoload.php")) {
    require_once(__DIR__."/../autoload.php");
    $dir = __DIR__."/../vendor/eru123/linker-installer";
} else {
    echo "Failed to load resources";
}

use Linker\Installer\Installer;

$installer = new Installer();

if(!$installer->init($dir,$argv ?? [],"v1.0"))
    Installer::echo("Linker installer failed to execute command! Try again!\n",33);
```

But when I installed it using composer global, the 'autoload.php' is included however I can't use the class I created on [src](https://github.com/eru123/linker-installer/tree/main/src) folder even it is on autoload psr-4 on my projects composer.json

```sh
C:\Users\pepe>linker -v
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Linker\Installer\Installer" not found in C:\Users\pepe\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\eru123\linker-installer\linker:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\pepe\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\eru123\linker-installer\linker on line 6

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Linker\Installer\Installer" not found in C:\Users\pepe\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\eru123\linker-installer\linker:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\pepe\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\eru123\linker-installer\linker on line 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! I change like this and the code is working.

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$dir = __DIR__;

require_once(__DIR__."/../../autoload.php"); 


use Linker\Installer\Installer;

$installer = new Installer();

if(!$installer->init($dir,$argv ?? [],"v1.0"))
    Installer::echo("Linker installer failed to execute command! Try again!\n",33);
```

But if you have a better solution or a standard solution please let me know and post your answer.